# Prove $p_k\circ f$ continuous $\implies$ f is continuous

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> Let $X_1,\dots X_n$ topological space and $p_k:X_1\times\cdots X_n\to X_k$ the projection to the kth component. Let $Y$ be topological space and 
>   $f:Y\to X_1\times\cdots\times X_n$ function s.t $\forall 1\le k\le n\quad p_k\circ f$ is continuous. Prove that $f$ is continuous.

I thought that since $p_k\circ f$ is continuous $\forall1\le k\le n$, $(p_k\circ f)^{-1}(O_k)\in\tau_{Y}$ (where $O_k\in\tau_k$  the topology of $(X_k,\tau_k)$) and then each open set in $\tau_{\pi}$ is a product of open sets from these topologies, i.e $$\forall O\in\tau_\pi,O=\bigcup_{i\in I}\prod_{k=1}^n O_{k,i}$$ (where $O_{k,i}$ is an open set in $\tau_k$)$$\Rightarrow f^{-1}(O)\in\tau_Y$$ but that's seems fishy to me. Am I (even not completely) right?

Comment: Each open set in the product topology is the **union** of products of open sets. So you're close to the target.

Comment: I added union before the product. Now that's correct?

Comment: You have forgotten to mention the union in the text, but the bigger problem is that you haven't said _why_ it follows that $f^{-1}(O)\in \tau_Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed $O = \bigcup_{i \in I}\prod_{k=1}^n O_{k,i}$, where $O$ is open in $\prod_{k=1}^n X_k$, $I$ is some index set, and for each $i$ we have open sets $O_{k,i} \in \tau_k$.

Note (this you did not write down) that $\prod_{k=1}^n O_{k,i} = \cap_{k=1}^n p_k^{-1}[O_{k,i}]$, and so $$f^{-1}[O] = f^{-1}[\bigcup_{i \in I}\prod_{k=1}^n O_{k,i}] = f^{-1} [\bigcup_{i \in I}\bigcap_{k=1}^n (p_k)^{-1}[O_{k,i}]] = \\ \bigcup_{i \in I} \bigcap_{k=1}^n f^{-1}[p_k^{-1}[O_{k,i}]]$$ (we use $f^{-1}$ commutes with intersections and unions) which equals $$\bigcup_{i \in I}\bigcap_{k=1}^n (p_k \circ f)^{-1}[O_{k,i}]]\text{.}$$

Now the assumptions yield that indeed $f^{-1}[O]$ is open, using that finite intersections and arbitrary unions of open sets are open.